# Error:Execution failed for task, finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: java, android-studio, build-error

I'm getting this error every time I try to run my project and can't seem to figure out how to fix it. I have tried multiple things to try fix it and still no joy. Any help would be much appreciated.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

This is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"


  /*  dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }*/

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.neil.studicom"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-mobile-services-android-sdk:2.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Comment: It's look like the you have the some problem while you create the string. Check this common error and I also got many time during my project. Check every java file and it's string variable.

Comment: Have you any other advice on how to overcome this issue? It has me very stuck.

Comment: I am sure that the error is within your Java files.. Check your Java files and may be your lastly created Java file have a problem to store string..

Comment: During my project development I faced that error and I tried to delete the `.idea`  folder and `.gradle` folder that may be worked for you... Please do backup of your project before you delete that both folder....

Comment: And let me know that it's work for you or not ?? If you still have problems infom me I try to solve that...

Comment: First delete only `.idea` folder try it may be worked and if not work than only delete the `.gradle` folder.. Don't worry about `.idea` folder Android stui automatically will create this folder...